# WIX - Major Upgrade Uninstalling files it didn't install

Tags: wix

I have divided my WIX installer into 2 primary MSI's, one is large and is rarely updated and the other is small and frequently updated.

They both install to the same directory (ie ..program files/MyCompany/MyProduct/), the issue I am having is that on an upgrade of the smaller installer the files from the large installer are being removed.

How can I prevent the smaller MSI installer from removing the larger MSI installer files on a Major upgrade? The bootstrapper detects (reg check) if the larger MSI is required and will download it as required and the smaller is assumed to always be required.

I am using WIX 3.6 with the default burn bootstrapper.

Bootstrapper:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:netfx='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension'>
<Bundle Name="MyProduct" Version="4.0.6156" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="cc5f7c9c-8e02-42b7-b202-a3b0865686c5" DisableModify="yes" DisableRepair="yes" UpdateUrl="URI TO SETUP">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense" />
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLicenseUrl" Value="URI TO LICENSE AGREEMENT" />
<WixVariable Id="WixStdbaLogo" Value="ClientLogo.png" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="NetDetect" 
                     Variable="NetFramework" 
                     Root="HKLM" 
                     Key="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" 
                     Value="Install" />

<util:ProductSearch Result="version" Guid="DF6C4673-A1B6-419F-B514-DBC096E6CFA8" Variable="ImgagingVersion"/>
    <Chain>
  <ExePackage Compressed="no" 
              DownloadUrl="URI TO DOT NET INSTALLER" 
              Id="DotNet4Install" 
              InstallCondition="NetFramework &lt;&gt; 1" 
              SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
              Permanent="yes"
              InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;MYPRODUCT&quot;"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Vital="yes"/>
  <MsiPackage Compressed="no" 
              DownloadUrl="URI TO LARGER INSTALLER" 
              Id="ImagingInstaller" 
              InstallCondition="ImgagingVersion &lt; v1.0.0.0"
              SourceFile="$(var.WIX.Setup.Accusoft.TargetDir)\LargeInstaller.msi" 
              Vital="yes"
              />
  <MsiPackage Compressed="no" 
              DownloadUrl="URI TO SMALLER INSTALLER" 
              Id="ClientServiceInstall"
              SourceFile="$(var.WIX.Setup.Client.TargetDir)\SmallInstaller.msi" 
              Vital="yes"/>
    </Chain>
</Bundle> </Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the issue I was having was because I was incrementing the version of the boot strapper on every update of the smaller msi installer, instead I am now only incrementing the version number of the msi.